# Making Exclamation Points more Visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After becoming accustomed to `False ==` in place of exclamation points, my coworker tends not to see them in code.  I am wondering if anyone can offer a suggestion for a way to configure Visual Studio 2010 (via an add-in or otherwise) to make them more noticeable (e.g. bolding them or changing their color).

Comment: Just making them bold doesn't seem to make them more noticeable, at least not in my configuration

Comment: Why don't he just get used to it as he got used to `False ==`?

Comment: @BrunoLM: That's what he plans to do.  I'm the one who is curious.  I don't think he even considered this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for ! then it will temporarily change background color to yellow.

Comment: I too would like a permanent way to make "!" stand out. It looks too much like I, l, and 1 (eye, ell, and one). It's a bad language design choice in my opinion. Either they should have used "Not", or punctuation that stands out more, like "@".